# 32bit console application cannot be started in 64bit process written in c#

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I see that quite similar topic has been discussed here but anyone has solved my problem so far.

I have this assignment:

1. I have .exe (32bit) utility to run with commands
2. this utility will be started with windows service on 64bit platform

I know that this is no possibility to run 32bit apps on 64bit process. Otherwise I found workaround by COM IPC communication.

So there is my solution:

Interface declaration of COM library:

```
namespace Win32ConsoleAppWrapper
{
  [GuidAttribute("5a6ab402-aa68-4d58-875c-fe26dea9c1cd"), ComVisible(true),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
  interface IKDUCompessor
  {
    event ProcessStarted processStarted;
    void RunKDUCompress(string comm);
  }
}
```

Class implementing the interface:

```
namespace Win32ConsoleAppWrapper
{

  [GuidAttribute("a1f4eb1a-b276-4272-90e0-0eb26e4273e0"), ComVisible(true),
  ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class KDUCompessor : IKDUCompessor
  {
    public static readonly string KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME = "kdu_compress.exe";

    public event ProcessStarted processStarted;

    public KDUCompessor() { }

    public void RunKDUCompress(string comm)
    {
      if(!File.Exists(KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME))
      {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("File {0} could not be found. Please check the bin directory.", KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME));
      }

      ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
      info.CreateNoWindow = false;
      info.UseShellExecute = true;
      info.FileName = String.Concat(KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME);
      info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      info.Arguments = comm;

      // Start the process with the info we specified.
      // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
      using(Process exeProcess = Process.Start(info))
      {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

The code is build with no error and no warnings. Then by regAsm.exe registered as COM.

Now I am trying to access to COM and call the method:

```
public class MyClass
{

#region COM Interface and class declaration

[
  ComImport(),
  Guid("5a6ab402-aa68-4d58-875c-fe26dea9c1cd"),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
]
public interface IKDUCompessor
{
  [PreserveSig]
  void RunKDUCompress(string comm);   

}

[
  ComImport,
  Guid("a1f4eb1a-b276-4272-90e0-0eb26e4273e0")
]
public class KDUCompessor { }

#endregion

protected void CallCOM(_command)
{
  if (IsCommandValid(_command))
  {
    // instance
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("a1f4eb1a-b276-4272-90e0-0eb26e4273e0"));
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    IKDUCompessor t = (IKDUCompessor)o;
    t.RunKDUCompress(_command);

  }
}
```

And I got a problems:

1. executing ends with exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled, class is not registered HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)), when assembly is registered by regasm.exe with no error
2. I cannot add COM reference to project in VS via add reference wizard, it ends with error dialog window: "A reference to 'assemblyName' could not be added. The ActiveX type library 'libary path' was exported from a .net assembly and cannot be added as a reference. Add a reference to the .net assembly instead."

I tried a lot of solutions but I was unsuccessful ... thanks for help.

Comment: You need a [surrogate](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) to adapt between the 32-bit and 64-bit COM types.

Comment: Why can't you spawn a 32-bit process from a 64-bit one? Process.Start should work.

Comment: It is fairly ironic that your COM wrapper suffers from the *exact* same problem.  You have to register it with the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe, the one from the Framework64 directory, not the Framework directory.  Which will make it execute in 64-bit mode.  Starting a 32-bit program from 64-bit code is not a problem, at most the file redirector may be an issue.  Document exactly where the exe is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that you can't *run* a 32-bit from a 64-bit process. You can not *use* a 32-bit DLL or COM-Control in a 64-bit process, but you can use `Process.Start` to start any process you want.

In your case it sounds like you don't even have to use the COM control you're describing (this causes more problems, even). Just do the following within your service (no matter whether 32- or 64-bit) and you're fine:

```
if(!File.Exists(KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME))
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("File {0} could not be found. Please check the bin directory.", KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME));
}

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.FileName = String.Concat(KDU_COMPRESS_LIBRARY_NAME);
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.Arguments = comm;

// Start the process with the info we specified.
// Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
using(Process exeProcess = Process.Start(info))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe little bit miss understanding. I need to run 32bit exe assembly within 64bit process (thats my win service). And this is not possible. That´s why I am using COM as workaround. But as I see, there is other problem with type register interop on Win7 which are not supported from MS as I read .. hmm

Comment: It **is** possible to run a 32bit exe assembly from a 64bit process using `Process.Start`. I've just written two sample applications (one starter 64 bit only and one application that's started by the starter 32 bit only) and the 64 bit application starts the 32 bit application via `Process.Start`.

Comment: Seems that I little bit complicated whole solution. Because in .exe assembly was missing one reference and I added it ass .dll (and all allocated in COM), which causes the problem and after download of new release of 3rd party app it works fine ... thanks to dependency walker. So your advice is right, thanks.